# Suddenly Entity Data Model wizard window crashes with MySQL DB 5.7.21.0

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL Community-5.7.21.0 database and Visual Studio 2017.
MySQL database is successfully Installed. Also, I have created a database
& some table.

My Problem is when I am trying to the establish the connection with
Entity Data Model wizard, after establishing the database configuration
in Entity Data Model wizard click Next button, then suddenly Entity Data
Model wizard window crashes.

Comment: Was it ever working?  Did you recently make any code changes?

Comment: If it used to work and doesn't work now, probably whatever changed is the culprit. That said - one of the only ways you can troubleshoot "wizards" is by implementing an orderly use of version control. Then you can inspect what has changed more easily. Good luck. Your question is essentially unanswerable as it is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No I have not write any code, I am just trying to connect the DB as a DataBase First Approach using EF6.

Answer (score 3):

I Found the solution for the above issue which I have posted.

1. Goto this path \Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\
2. Search the .dll file name start with **MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6**, --> Ckeck the file details using right click -->
   Properties --> Details tab. Check the file version: Example:(6.10.6.0 or 6.9.8.0 etc).
3. Goto https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/
   and download the same version whatever you got in the file version. and Install the same.
4. Goto your Visual Studio project and click on view --> Other Windows --> Package Manager Console
   and Install from there: **pm> Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity -Version** (Whatever you got the file version like 6.10.6, 6.9.8 etc).
5. Restart the visual studio. This problem will be solved.

Cheers!

Comment: Any old version of connector can be downloaded from this ftp site: http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/MySQL/Downloads/Connector-Net/

Comment: On web is connector only in version 6.9.12
When I installed same version
- Install-Package MySql.Data.Entity -Version 
- Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.9.12
Problem was solved

Thanks you